# Creating SSH key on Jenkins Master - Centos Yum Install

Tags: centos6, ssh-keys, jenkins, build-server

I have installed Jenkins on a Centos VM as I am looking at replacing Bamboo, I have it all up and running by following the install [instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions). That went fine, I then wanted to spin up a Slave, I created a second VM, created a user on it, created a SSH key for that user. I then created a Slave node in Jenkins but when I created the account in Jenkins for the Slave machine and supplied the SSH Private key I got and error. Which is right as I did not put the Master SSH pub key on the Slave in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

It looks like the Centos Yum install does not create ssh keys for the user running Jenkins, I did my Google fu and from what I read I need this to do what I want to do. I did try SU as the on the machine but with no luck. I would like to know how I need to do this, as I would sooner use SSH keys.

In saying all of this I have got a slave going by using the SSH option using a password, it works but it's not the way I want to do this.

Any help would be super!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem. What I did was:

1. On the master change to root user: `su root`
2. Execute: `passwd jenkins`
3. Specify a password for the jenkins user
4. Change to the jenkins user (and supply password from step 3): `su jenkins`
5. Run `ssh-keygen`

That solved the problem for me. I could not do `sudo passwd jenkins`, I had to change to the root user. You might also want to add the remote server to the know_hosts file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I have now got it working using SSH keys :) The only other part I needed to do is update the passwd file to set BASH for login. Once I did that I was fine.

Answer (score 30):

A more suitable way to achieve the same thing would be to run:

```
# sudo -u jenkins ssh-keygen
```

That will generate the key for you here:
/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer

Comment: In my specific use case (gerrit) I had to ssh into the server to get the known_hosts entry added.